# Morphisms of quasi-projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(k)$ be a quasi-projective variety. By [Görtz, Wedhorn](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf) (page 32, Proposition 1.65) in order to show that
$$h:Y\to \mathbb{P}^m(k), y\mapsto (f_0(y):\dots :f_m(y))$$
is a morphism of prevarieties where $f_i\in k[X_0,\dots,X_n]$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree which don't vanish simultaneously it suffices to show that each component of the restriction $h_{\mid h^{-1}(U_j)}$ is a morphism of prevarieties.

My questions:

- Why does that suffice?
- Where do we use that $Y$ is an open subset of a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$?

My thoughts:

By the definition of a morphism of prevarieties we have to show:

- $h$ is continuous
- for all open $U \subseteq \mathbb{P}^m(k)$ and all $f\in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m(k)}(U)$ we have $f\circ h_{\mid h^{-1}(U)}\in \mathcal{O}_Y(h^{-1}(U))$.

Maybe in the last point we can restrict ourselves to $U_i$ by Proposition 1.44 and the glueing property. But still we have to show something different than stated in Görtz:
$$f\circ h_{\mid h^{-1}(U_i)}\in \mathcal{O}_Y(h^{-1}(U_i))$$

Comment: I think this follows because the collection of restrictions of $h$ covers the domain and codomain. Showing it on the restrictions is enough because patching morphisms works in the way you expect. For example, if you have two continuous functions which agree on the overlap, then they patch together into one continuous function.